# Read strings from .exe files(Like Strings.exe) in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, exe

I want to write a program for read/extract all of the valid strings in a .exe files (For example: "This program must be run under Win" or "MZ"), Exactly like `Strings.exe` of `sysinternals`.
Actually i want to scan a `.exe` file and if that contain special string value such as `"ekrn.exe"` or `"Filrefox.exe"` then detect that file as a suspicious file (Killing `ekrn.exe` or inject malcode to `firefox.exe`).

I wrote the following code in Delphi :

```
const
  TargetName = 'E:\AntiDebugg.exe';
var
  hFile: THandle;
  tmp: AnsiString;
  dwFileSize, lChar, lSearch: Integer;
  dwNumRead: Cardinal;
  dwBuffer: array of AnsiChar;
begin
  mmo1.Clear;

  hFile := CreateFileA(TargetName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

  dwFileSize := GetFileSize(hFile, nil);
  SetLength(dwBuffer, dwFileSize);

  lChar := 0;
  lSearch := 0;

  while lChar <= dwFileSize do
  begin
    ReadFile(hFile, dwBuffer[lChar], SizeOf(dwBuffer), dwNumRead, nil);
    while dwBuffer[lChar] <> '' do
    begin
      tmp := tmp + dwBuffer[lChar];
      Inc(lChar, 1);
    end;
    lSearch := 0;
    Inc(lChar, 1);
  end;
  mmo1.Text := (tmp);
  CloseHandle(hFile);
```

The result of running my code is  (A small piece):

```
MZPےے¸@؛´   ح!¸Lح!گگThis program must be run under Win32
$7PEL
%0فQà´أ\
¤"0Bگب.textd­ .itext| .data`@.bssطN.idata\
@.didataب@.tls.rdata@.reloc¤"@.rsrc@@@Boolean@alseTrueSystem4@AnsiCharP@    Charےh@Integerے€@Byteک@Wordے°@Pointerؤ@Cardinalےےےà@    NativeIntےےےü@
NativeUIntے@ShortStringے,@  PAnsiChar0@D@stringT@TClassŒ@h@HRESULTے€@TGUID
```

But this isn't my desired result and my desired result is :

```
MZP
This program must be run under Win32
.text
`.itext
`.data
.bss
.idata
.didata
.tls
.rdata
@.reloc
B.rsrc
Boolean
False
True
System
AnsiChar
Char
Integer
Byte
Word
Pointer
Cardinal
NativeInt
NativeUInt
ShortString
PAnsiChar0
string
TClass
HRESULT
TGUID
```

- In this example the `AntiDebugg.exe` compiled by Delphi .

The result of `Strings.exe` for strings of "AntiDebugg.exe"

[image]

Any idea ?
What should i to do ?

Comment: You do not do what [`strings(1)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strings&sektion=1) does. Please consider reading a whole description.

Comment: Some of the chars in [`ASCII range`](http://www.asciitable.com/) are undisplayable. 1) Scan the buffer from the first displayable char until you reach one which cannot be displayed (or, which you don't want to display). And that's one word which you can store somewhere. 2) Go to step 1

Comment: Pay particular attention to "printable character" in the link mentioned in the first comment. Why are you occasionally assigning 0 to lSearch?

Comment: Did you consider reading the source code to strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsciiDump coded by {steve10120@ic0de.org}

```
function FileToPtr(szFilePath: string; var pFile: Pointer;

  var dwFileSize: DWORD): Boolean;

var

  hFile: DWORD;

  dwRead: DWORD;

begin

  Result := FALSE;

  hFile := CreateFile(PChar(szFilePath), GENERIC_READ, 0, nil,

    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

  if (hFile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then

  begin

    dwFileSize := GetFileSize(hFile, nil);

    if (dwFileSize > 0) then                                  

    begin

      pFile := VirtualAlloc(nil, dwFileSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

      if (Assigned(pFile)) then

      begin

        SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);

        ReadFile(hFile, pFile^, dwFileSize, dwRead, nil);

        if (dwRead = dwFileSize) then

          Result := TRUE;

      end;

    end;

    CloseHandle(hFile);

  end;

end;



function FindASCIIStringsA(szFilePath: string; dwMinLength: DWORD;

  szDumpPath: string): Boolean;

var

  pFile: Pointer;

  dwFileSize: DWORD;

  i: DWORD;

  szDump: string;

  dwLength: DWORD;

  hFile: TextFile;

begin

  Result := FALSE;

  if (FileToPtr(szFilePath, pFile, dwFileSize)) then

  begin

    dwLength := 0;

    AssignFile(hFile, szDumpPath);

    // yeah I don't like it but its easiest for writing lines..

    Rewrite(hFile);

    for i := 0 to (dwFileSize - 1) do

    begin

      if (PByte(DWORD(pFile) + i)^ in [$20 .. $7E]) then

      begin

        szDump := szDump + Char(PByte(DWORD(pFile) + i)^);

//        WriteLn(hFile, '0x' + IntToHex(i - dwLength, 8) + ': ' + szDump);

        Inc(dwLength);

      end

      else

      begin

        if (dwLength >= dwMinLength) then

          WriteLn(hFile, '0x' + IntToHex(i - dwLength, 8) + ': ' + szDump);

        dwLength := 0;

        szDump := '';

      end;

    end;

    if (FileSize(hFile) > 0) then

      Result := TRUE;

    CloseFile(hFile);

    VirtualFree(pFile, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

  end;

end;

function FindASCIIStrings(szFilePath:string; dwMinLength:DWORD; szDumpPath:string):Boolean;

var

  pFile:      Pointer;

  dwFileSize: DWORD;

  IDH:        PImageDosHeader;

  INH:        PImageNtHeaders;

  i:          DWORD;

  szDump:     string;

  dwLength:   DWORD;

  hFile:      TextFile;

begin

  Result := FALSE;

  if (FileToPtr(szFilePath, pFile, dwFileSize)) then

  begin

    IDH := pFile;

    if (IDH^.e_magic = IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) then

    begin

      INH := Pointer(DWORD(pFile) + IDH^._lfanew);

      if (INH^.Signature = IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) then

      begin

        dwLength := 0;

        AssignFile(hFile, szDumpPath); // yeah I don't like it but its easiest for writing lines..

        Rewrite(hFile);

        for i := INH^.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders to (dwFileSize - 1) do

        begin

          if (PByte(DWORD(pFile) + i)^ in [$20..$7E]) then

          begin

            szDump := szDump + Char(PByte(DWORD(pFile) + i)^);

            Inc(dwLength);

          end

          else

          begin

            if (dwLength >= dwMinLength) then

              WriteLn(hFile, '0x' + IntToHex(i - dwLength, 8) + ': ' + szDump);

            dwLength := 0;

            szDump := '';

          end;

        end;

        if (FileSize(hFile) > 0) then

          Result := TRUE;

        CloseFile(hFile);

      end;

    end;

    VirtualFree(pFile, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

  end;

end;

procedure TForm2.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

FindASCIIStrings('e:\AntiDebugg.exe', 2,

    IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(param  str(0))) +

    ExtractFileName(paramstr(1)) + '.dmp')

end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
const
  TargetName = 'E:\AntiDebugg.exe';
  MinStringLength = 2;

var
  hFile: THandle;
  hMapping: THandle;
  pView: Pointer;  
  dwFileSize: DWORD;
  pCurrent, pEOF, pStart: PAnsiChar;
  iLen: Integer;
begin
  mmo1.Clear;

  hFile := CreateFile(TargetName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  if hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    dwFileSize := GetFileSize(hFile, nil);
    if dwFileSize = $FFFFFFFF then RaiseLastOSError;

    hMapping := CreateFileMapping(hFile, nil, PAGE_READONLY, 0, dwFileSize, nil);
    if hMapping = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      pView := MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, dwFileSize);
      if pView = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
      try
        pCurrent := PAnsiChar(pView);
        pEOF := pCurrent + dwFileSize;
        pStart := nil;

        while pCurrent < pEOF do
        begin
          if pCurrent^ in [#9, #10, #13, #32..#128] then
          begin
            if pStart = nil then
              pStart := pCurrent;
          end
          else if pStart <> nil then
          begin
            iLen := Integer(pCurrent - pStart);
            if iLen >= MinStringLength then
            begin
              SetString(tmp, pStart, iLen);
              mmo1.Lines.Add(tmp);
            end;
            pStart := nil;
          end;
          Inc(pCurrent);
        end;
      finally
        UnmapViewOfFile(pView);
      end;
    finally
     CloseHandle(hMapping);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hFile);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @FreeConsulting: That is a C/C++ function, it is not available in Delphi.

Comment: `function isprint(c: Integer): Integer; cdecl; external 'msvcrt.dll';`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your code. Its almost completed but needs to a parsing section ;), Thanks all.